# PrestaShop smarty config problem "exec() has been disabled"

Tags: php, prestashop

I have a problem with the store on PS, namely I get the error message that the function exec () in smarty.config.inc.php is disabled. Before this error, I did not change anything in the store or on the server. The exec () function is unlikely to be disabled in the main php.ini files because it works, for example, in the controllers of this store. As if it were disabled only for this particular file. If I remove this function from this file, the website works but does not load most things. At the moment, the store page is white and only contains this error message.

`Fatal error: exec() has been disabled for security reasons in /usr/home/workwork/domains/my_domain.com/public_html/config/smarty.config.inc.php on line 207`

When I try to log into the admin panel there are no panel styles or functionality.

I don't know how to fix it, thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: contact your host provider, because exec() is different with hook::exec() (exec method inside hook class)

Comment: Thanks, it's working

Comment: i m happy if it s working, chears !